# How do I require an enum as a strong typed parameter?

Tags: c#, .net, enums

I may be going about this entirely wrong so I am open to any and all suggestions. What I am trying to do is require the `StatusType` parameter in this:

```
Response(StatusType.Submit, message);
```

To be limited to a certain set of types which will return a constant string value. So far I have come up with this solution:

```
public class Response
{
    private StatusType _status;

    Response(StatusType status, string message)
    {
        _status = status;
    }

    public string Status
    {
        get
        {
            return Enum.GetName(typeof(StatusType), _status);
        }
    }
}

public enum StatusType
{
    Fail,
    Success,
    Response,
    Confirm
}
```

But I now realize the enum parameter is weak-typed and will allow me to enter a string value instead. Can anyone help me? I have a feeling that an enum is not my solution but I'm not sure of another way.

Comment: Where in your example code is it allowing you to use a string?

Comment: I apologize, Visual Studio doesn't throw an error when I build with: `Response("String", message);`

Comment: Are you *sure* you are using the `Response` class you think you are?  What you are seeing doesn't really make any sense.  I tested it and I get the error I expect, `Error CS1503 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'ConsoleApplication2.StatusType'`.  It's possible you are using a different `Response` class from another namespace without realizing it.

Comment: Another note that supports my idea you may be using a different `Response` class without realizing it.  I wasn't able to actually instantiate your class because the constructor wasn't public; I had to modify your code to even be able to call it.

Comment: @BradleyUffner Thanks for the help! My team is using both VB and C#. It seems that C# throws the error but VB does not.

Comment: VB may not throw the error if `Option Strict` is turned off. With Option Strict set to off VB will often try to "helpfully" convert things to different types.

Comment: Oh alright, that makes sense. @BradleyUffner

Comment: I recommend ALWAYS turning `Option Strict` on when working in VB, it helps avoid all kinds of hard to track down errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the comments, you are getting the error when using this class from a VB project.

When `Option Strict` is turned off, VB will try to "helpfully" convert objects between "compatible" types.  This often hides mistakes and causes some really hard to track down errors.  I recommend always turning 'Option Strict` On when developing in Visual Basic; it will help you write much better code.

You can turn Option Strict on for the entire project from the `Compile` tab in the project properties (recommended way), or for individual files by adding `Option Strict On` to the top of the file outside of any class definitions.